# Python Multi-threaded socket listener error with threads not releasing

Tags: python, multithreading, file, sockets

I have 500+ units in the world that connects to my server and dump their data. Up to now i have been using a PHP script to act as a socket listener, but I need to go multi-threaded as the load is increasing and PHP can not keep up. I am quite new to Python and decided to use it for my new platform, over the past few days i have struggled and tried many examples to no avail. Through my search i came across some questions trying to answer this problem, but none did. I will attach my code.

The problem : as the units connect to the server and the server accepts it, the server creates a new thread to handle the connection, the problem comes when the unit drops the connection the thread stays open and active and the total thread count grows, and this is linked to the system limit : "number of open files", i can increase this limit but this only make it a time bomb , it does not solve this.

Please help.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing
import socket
import sys
import pprint
import datetime
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime
import re
import select
import resource
import threading

max_connections = 1024
max_connections_set = max_connections
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (max_connections_set, max_connections_set))



#the incomming port
the_global_port = xxxx #(any port)

#display id
the_global_id = "UNIT TYPE"




class ConnectionObject(object):
  the_id = None

  the_socket = None
  the_socket_address = None
  the_socket_address_ip = None
  the_socket_address_port = None

  the_server = None

  the_process = None
  the_process_id = None
  the_process_name = None

  the_imei = None
  identifier = ""

  # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer 
  def __init__(self, in_process_nr, in_process , in_socket , in_socket_address, in_server):
    self.the_id = in_process_nr
    self.the_process = in_process
    self.the_process_id = self.the_process.exitcode
    self.the_process_name = self.the_process.name


    self.the_socket = in_socket
    self.the_socket_address = in_socket_address
    self.the_socket_address_ip = self.the_socket_address[0]
    self.the_socket_address_port = self.the_socket_address[1]


    self.the_server = in_server

    self.identifier = str(self.the_id) + " " + str(self.the_process_name) + " " + str(self.the_socket_address_ip) + " " + str(self.the_socket_address_port) + " "
  #end def init
#end def class  

def processData(the_connection_object , the_data):
  def mysql_open_connection_inside():
    try:
      the_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "127.0.0.1",
                          user="user",
                          passwd="password",
                          db="mydb")
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
      print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
      time.sleep(30)
      try:
        the_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "127.0.0.1",
                            user="user",
                            passwd="password",
                            db="mydb")
      except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
        sys.exit(0) 
      #end time 2  
    #end try except

    return the_conn
  #end def mysql_open_connection                    



  conn = mysql_open_connection_inside()
  x = conn.cursor()

  add_rawdata = ("INSERT INTO RawData"
                 "(ID,RawData,Type) "
                 "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")

  data_raw = ('123456', 'ABCD','')



  records_inserted = 0


  the_connection_object.the_imei = ""


  #global clients
  imei = ""
  try:
    thedata = ""
    thedata = " ".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in the_data)

    record_to_save = ' '.join(thedata)


    seqtoreply = ""
    seqtoreply = "OK"

    #reply part
    if (seqtoreply != ""): #reply to unit
      try:
        the_connection_object.the_socket.sendall(seqtoreply)
        #echoout(the_connection_object.identifier+"We Replyed With : " + seqtoreply)
      except:
        echoout(the_connection_object.identifier+"Send Reply Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
      #end except
    #end of if 


    the_id = "some generated id"
    data_raw  = (the_id, werk_data, 'UNIT')
    try:
      x.execute(add_rawdata, data_raw)
      conn.commit()
      echoout(the_connection_object.identifier+"Raw Data Saved.")
    except:
      conn.rollback()
      echoout(the_connection_object.identifier+" Raw Data NOT Saved : " + str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
    #end of data save insert  
    #echoout("=============================")
    endme = 1
    echoout("")
    conn.close()
  #end try
  except:
    conn.close()
    echoout(the_connection_object.identifier+"Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
  #end  try except
#end  def handel function



def handle_p(processnr, server, connection, address):
  this_connection = ConnectionObject(processnr,multiprocessing.current_process(), connection, address, server)
  thisprocess = multiprocessing.current_process()
  this_connection.the_id = ""
  the_address = this_connection.the_socket_address_ip
  the_port = this_connection.the_socket_address_port

  try:
    echoout("New connection from : "+str(the_address)+" on port "+str(the_port))
    close_the_socket = False
    while True:
      #--------------------- recive part -------------------------------------------------
      data = connection.recv(512)
      thedata = ""
      thedata = " ".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in data)
      if ((thedata == "") or (thedata == " ") or (data == False)):
        echoout("Socket Closed Remotely : No Data")
        close_the_socket = True
        break
      #end - if data blank
      else :
        processData(this_connection, data)
      #end there is data  
      echoout("=============================")
    #end if while true
  #end try
  except:
    print "handling request, Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    close_the_socket = True
    connection.close()
  finally:
    close_the_socket = True
    echoout("Closing socket")
    connection.close()
  #end  try finally
#end  def handel function

def mysql_update(update_statement, update_values):
  conn_update = MySQLdb.connect(host= "127.0.0.1",
                    user="user",
                    passwd="password",
                    db="mydb")
  x_update = conn_update.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

  rawdata_data = (update_statement)
  data_rawdata = (update_values)
  allupdateok = False
  #end if there is more  
  try:
    x_update.execute(rawdata_data, data_rawdata)
    conn_update.commit()
    allupdateok = True
    conn_update.close()
  except:
    conn_update.rollback()
    allupdateok = False
    conn_update.close()
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
  #end of data save insert  
  if (allupdateok == False):
    echoout("Update Raw Data Table Error")
  #end if update
  return allupdateok
#end def mysqlupdate



def echoout(thestring):
  datestring = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  if (thestring != ""):
    outstring = datestring + " " + thestring
    print outstring
  else :
    outstring = thestring
    print outstring
#end - def echoout




class Server(object):
  threads = []
  all_threads = []
  high_proc = ""
  def __init__(self, hostname, port):
    self.hostname = hostname
    self.port = port

  def start(self):
    echoout("Listening for conncetions")
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.bind((self.hostname, self.port))
    self.socket.listen(10)
    process_number = 1

    inputs = [self.socket]
    while True:
      inready, outready, excready = select.select(inputs, [], [], 30);
      for s in inready:
        if s == self.socket:
          conn, address = self.socket.accept()
          high_processname = ""
          echoout("Got a connection...")
          process = threading.Thread(target=handle_p, args=(process_number,self, conn, address))
          high_processname = process.name
          self.high_proc = high_processname
          process.daemon = True
          process.start()
          self.all_threads.append((process,conn))
          ts = time.time()
          st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
          self.threads.append((process_number,conn,st,0,process))
          process_number = process_number + 1

          print "ACTIVE Threads = " + str(threading.activeCount())

          the_total_count = 0 
          dead_count = 0
          alive_count = 0
          for the_thread in self.all_threads :
            if (the_thread[0].is_alive() == True):
              alive_count = alive_count + 1
            else :
              dead_count = dead_count + 1
              the_thread[1].close()
              the_thread[0].join(0.3)

              self.all_threads.pop(the_total_count)
            #end if alive else 
            the_total_count = the_total_count + 1
          #end for threads  

          print "LIVE Threads = " + str(alive_count)
          print "DEAD Threads = " + str(dead_count)
          print "TOTAL Threads = " + str(the_total_count)
          print ""


        #end if s = socke, new connection
      #end for loop
    #end while truw
    self.socket.close()
  #end def start

#main process part
if __name__ == "__main__":

  start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
  start_port = the_global_port

  #start server
  server = Server(start_ip, start_port)
  try:
    print "Listening on " , start_port
    server.start()
  except:
    print "unexpected, Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
  finally:
    print "shutting down"

    active_clients = 0
    for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
      try:
        active_clients = active_clients + 1
        process.terminate()
        #process.join()
      except:
        print "Process not killed = " + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
      #end try except 
    #close mysql connection
    print "Active clients  = " + str(active_clients)
  #end try finally
  server.socket.close()
  server.threads = []
  server = None
  print "All done."
#end def main
```

Comment: `the problem comes when the unit drops the connection the thread stays open and active and the total thread count grows` Why are you not shutting the threads? http://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/2382792

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is silly to use threads when you can have 500+ connected clients, you should go asynchronous - look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) for example for
a very good library, or at least use `select` (see Python documentation).

Then, your code to close the socket in `handle_p` looks good, indeed when
the `recv()` call comes back with an empty string it means the remote
end is disconnected so you break the `while`, fine.

However, it looks like the remote closed the connection but it is not
detected on your side (`recv()` doesn't return). The best would be
then to have a kind of heartbeat to know when you can close the
connection.

Comment: Thanks, i tried gevent now, still getting the same problem, i also included detection on the recv() for dead connections, still no luck

Comment: Please show the new code ; how can you detect dead connections on recv? With a timeout?